# Как правильно реализовать ввод в мой класс BigInteger?

Tags: c++, ооп, типы-данных, динамические-структуры, длинная-арифметика

Вот мой класс:

```
class BigInteger
{
private:
    const size_t base = 65536; 
    vector<size_t> digits;
public:
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, BigInteger& object);
};

istream& operator >> (istream& in, BigInteger& object) //работает независимо от base в 10-ричной системе счисления
{
    string input;
    in >> input;
    object.digits.clear(); 

    for (string::reverse_iterator i = input.rbegin(); i != input.rend(); i++)
    {
        object.digits.push_back(*i - '0');
    }
    return in;
}
```

Однако есть проблема: я хочу сделать так, чтобы числа со входа переводились в нужную систему счисления (в моем случае `size_t base = 65536`) и уже эти числа поступали на вход моего объекта класса. Вопрос как это реализовать? Ведь по идее, надо как-то делить мои числа и узнавать от них остатки? Но как? Кроме идеи вычитания (ну ведь деление - сокращенное вычитание) и даже она кажется мне достаточно сложноватой для реализации. и не смотря на это она мне ооооочень долгой.  Вопрос как реализовать мою идею?

Comment: зачем для ввода в вектор целых  вам понадобился строковой объект?  Просто читайте сразу в вектор эти символы

Comment: Вы также могли  sizeof(size_t) - 1; байтов читать в один элемент вектора, а не одну цифру

Answer (score 0):

На C++ объяснять долго и лезут всякие "правильные" вещи вроде чтения из потока, функции на итераторах и тому подобное. Поэтому псевдокод, который на самом деле рабочий код на Python. Перевод на C++ оставляю читателю.

`from_list_base` - функция чтения числа из списка десятичных цифр. В качестве аккумулятора длинное целое. Начинаем с нуля, с каждой новой цифрой умножаем аккумулятор на 10 и добавляем эту цифру к сумме:

```
def from_list_base(base, digits):
    n = BigInteger(0)
    for d in digits:
        n = n * base + d
    return n
   
assert repr(from_list_base(10, [1, 2, 3, 4])) == '1234'
```

Цифры можно группировать, база должна быть степенью 10. Тогда исходное текстовое представление числа удобно разрезать на кусочки и каждый кусочек превратить в число средствами C++. Позволяет уменьшить число умножений в основном цикле. Конечно база должна помещаться в целочисленный тип С++ (в вашем случае 10000, не больше):

```
assert repr(from_list_base(100, [12, 34])) == '1234'
```

Теперь мы умеем читать число из строки любой длины. Чтение не самое быстрое, так как число в аккумуляторе все время удлиняется и операция `n * base` делается всё дольше и дольше. Время работы будет `N^2`, где `N` - число цифр в исходном тексте.

Если в типе `BigInteger` реализовано быстрое умножение чисел, то можно прочитать число из текста быстрее. Эффект будет заметен только на достаточно длинных текстах - сотни, тысячи цифр.

Умножение в столбик для чисел из `N` и `M` цифр занимает время пропорциональное `MN`. Быстрое умножение - это любой алгоритм который работает быстрее: умножение [Карацубы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%8B), [Шёнхаге-Штрассена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A8%D1%91%D0%BD%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5_%E2%80%94_%D0%A8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Если такое умножение реализовано, то читать можно быстрее при помощи "разделяй и властвуй". Цифры числа разбиваются на две половинки (`digits[:m]` - старшие разряды и `digits[m:]` - младшие разряды), каждая читается рекурсивно, затем составляется результат: `10^p * high + low`. Если цифр мало, запускаем базовый метод. Граница в этом примере занижена, её нужно подбирать измеряя производительность:

```
threshould = 2

def from_list(base, digits):
    if len(digits) < threshould:
        return from_list_base(base, digits)

    m = len(digits) // 2
    high = from_list(base, digits[:m])
    low = from_list(base, digits[m:])
    factor = power(BigInteger(base), len(digits) - m)
    return factor * high + low
```

Функция `power` - быстрое возведение в степень. Обычное последовательное умножение в цикле уничтожит все усилия по ускорению:

```
def power(n, e):
    if e == 0:
        return BigInteger(1)
    if e % 2 == 0:
        n2 = power(n, e // 2)
        return n2 * n2
    return n * power(n, e - 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Как-то мне тоже понадобилась длинная арифметика. Но использовать GMP было нельзя, так как длинная арифметика нужна была для микроконтроллеров без операционной системы и кучи. Пришлось написать свою библиотеку С++ шаблонов для работы с длинными целыми числами. Вот ссылка:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/muntl/

Там в архиве есть и описание на русском языке.

Comment: Приведите код, отвечающий за ввод числа (то, о чём спрашивает ТС), иначе это выглядит как реклама.

Comment: Или хотя бы алгоритм перевода без делений, как просит ТС. По ссылке я нашёл только скачивание каких-то архивов, посмотреть ваш код онлайн не смог.

Comment: Хорошо бы основную часть в ответ перенести)

Comment: На этом сайте (sourceforge.net) не предусмотрен просмотр кода онлайн. Можно только считать архив проекта и поглядеть исходники и описание. Что касается алгоритмов, то смысла приводить их нет. Так как подход к построению BigInteger у меня и у ТС кардинально отличается. Я храню числа в двоичном виде в массиве и не перевожу их в другую систему счисления. Это позволяет максимально использовать аппаратную арифметику процессора и таким образом сильно ускоряет работу.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 так если ваш код не будет отвечать на вопрос автора, то зачем вы привели ссылку на него?)

Comment: Этот код отвечает на главный вопрос - как надо строить BigInteger. Как-то на просторах интернета я видел проект BigInteger, в котором автор работал со строковыми представлениями чисел. Ну вот буквально, хранил текстовые строки. А чтобы сложить два числа автор парсил строку, к примеру "236514", и складывал с другой строкой "883027". Конечно, теоретически можно и так, но... :-(

Comment: @pepsicoca1 вопрос автора в другом был (*Как правильно реализовать ввод в мой класс BigInteger?*
). Думаю, если бы его интересовала готовая реализация, а не самостоятельное написание, он бы просто взял готовую библиотеку.

Comment: @Suvitruf - Andrei Apanasik Вы имеете ввиду - вставить в ответ описание этой библиотеки шаблонов?

Comment: @pepsicoca1 вставить в ответ информацию о том, как библиотека может помочь в решении вопроса.